# What are some example of `browser default behavior` that will be prevented by `event.preventDefault()`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I quite understand that `event.preventDefault()` will prevent any default behavior triggered by an event on browser, **but this definition is too broad for me**, for example what are those **event default behavior** on browser? since it's quite common to find developers use `event.preventDefault()` but I still don't understand what kind of behavior they're trying to prevent.

Comment: For example, if you want to build a drag and drop file upload app, you would want to stop the browser opening the file the use has drop into your app, and the

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click on a link, such as to `http://example.com`, your browser's default behavior will be to take you to `http://example.com`.

If you `preventDefault` in a click handler, the browser will no longer change your window location.

```js
document.querySelector('.prevent-default').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com">Normal Example</a>
<a class="prevent-default" href="http://example.com">Prevented Example</a>
```

Other examples include:

- `submit` has associated form submission
- `mousedown` has associated text selection
- `keydown` has associated input
- `touchstart` may have associated scrolling/zooming behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

one quick example is `click` event. Let's say you have a tag like

```
<a href="/my-sub-page.html" class='ajax-link'>
```

default behavior will be when you click this link it will take you to the /my-sub-page.html page. but if you want to avoid page refresh and instead you want to use ajax. then you will use

```
$('.ajax-link').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
     url : $(this).attr('href'),
     success : function(response){

        $('.my-content').html(response);
      }
  })
});
```

or another example can be form submits. Similar to above, you canprevent default behavior of form submission, and use ajax and get result from post request without loading the page.

Answer (score 1):

There are many default browser actions:

- `mousedown` – starts the selection (move the mouse to select).
- `click` on `<a href="">` - open the page.
- `click` on `<input type="checkbox">` – checks/unchecks the input.
- `submit` – clicking an `<input type="submit">` or hitting Enter inside a form field causes this event to happen, and the browser submits the form after it.
- `keydown` – pressing a key may lead to adding a character into a field, or other actions.
- `contextmenu` – the event happens on a right-click, the action is to show the browser context menu.
  etc.

Answer (score 0):

The **event.preventDefault()** method stops the default action of an element from happening.

For example:

- Prevent a submit button from submitting a form
- Prevent a link from following the URL

Use the **event.isDefaultPrevented()** method to check whether the **preventDefault()** method was called for the event.